# Missing msbuild during building vtk with msvc 2015 on windows7

Tags: cmake, msbuild, vtk, cmake-gui

I am trying to build vtk on windows 7 with msvc 2015 with this instruction:

https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Windows

I get this build error:

[image]

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Error "Failed to run MSBuild command" is **unrelated to exact project** your build; it is related to *general* usage of CMake with Visual Studio. So you may search other posts with the same error message.

Comment: Tried, this doesn't help, thats why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the problem I had to go to the File menu in the dialog, ...clear cache and set compiler to msvc2015.